# how to fetch data in range using timestamp - Firebase, Android, Real-time Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase real-time database to store and retrieve data but for some reason, I am unable to achieve what I want.

I want to get 20 records at a time on swipe refresh layout.

My data looks like:
[image: data structure]

Initially, I load 50 records:

```
chat.limitToLast(default_num_of_messages).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                Map map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
                String user_id =  map.get("user_id").toString();
                String message = map.get("message").toString();
                String timestamp = map.get("timestamp").toString();

                Log.d("MAP", map.toString());
                ChatMessage chat_message = new ChatMessage();
                chat_message.setUser_id(user_id);
                chat_message.setMessage(message);
                chat_message.setTimestamp(Long.parseLong(timestamp));
                Log.d("CHAT MSG", chat_message.toString());

                if(Integer.parseInt(user_id) == Utils.getInstance().getLoggedInUser().getId()) {
                    addMessageBox(chat_message, 1);
                }
                else{
                    addMessageBox(chat_message, 2);
                }
            }
```

after these on refresh, I want to load 20 more. I am trying to do something like these. but it does not seem to return.

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    if(refresh_toggle) {
        swipe_view.setRefreshing(true);
        Log.d("CHAT", "REFRESHED!!!");
        //reload new data
        chat.orderByChild("timestamp").endAt(10).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                Map map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
                String user_id =  map.get("user_id").toString();
                String message = map.get("message").toString();
                String timestamp = map.get("timestamp").toString();

                Log.d("CHATS", map.toString());
                ChatMessage chat_message = new ChatMessage();
                chat_message.setUser_id(user_id);
                chat_message.setMessage(message);
                chat_message.setTimestamp(Long.parseLong(timestamp));

                swipe_view.setRefreshing(false);
                if(Integer.parseInt(user_id) == Utils.getInstance().getLoggedInUser().getId()) {
                    addMessageBox(chat_message, 1);
                }
                else{
                    addMessageBox(chat_message, 2);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see I am trying to orderByChild "timestamp" and then tried different combination of startAt(), endAt() but nothing seem to work.

Comment: Were your data mixed or already sorted?

Comment: @ThiệnKopites already sorted. all i need is a way to pull 20 at a time from a current point. i can keep track of which was the last record pulled using timestamp but i want to use these timestamp value to fetch next 20 records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 int number_item_load = 10; //changed number if you want
    public void loadMore(int offset, String theLastValue) {
        // theLastValue: depend on your orderByChild() 's value
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Utils.FB_ROOT);
        mEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                if (isAlreadyAttach()) {
                    // Get your item and callback to view and insert to listView
                }
            } ...
        };


        mDatabase.orderByChild("yourvalue").startAt(theLastValue).limitToFirst(number_item_load ).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // TODO Finished loaded number_item_load  item
                OnLoadedFinish(); // 
                mDatabase.removeEventListener(mEventListener); // Remove listener after load
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        mDatabase.orderByChild("yourvalue").startAt(theLastValue).limitToFirst(number_item_load ).addChildEventListener(mEventListener);
    }
```

It worked perfectly in my case. Goodluck

Comment: @Thien Kopites what is "idLastOne" in my case? how can I get one

Comment: I already commented on my code, 
That is your last dataSnapshot key.  startAt() have to know where he will start. 
For instance: You loaded 15 chat for the first time.
and you are loading more 10 chat items.   "idLastOne" here is the dataSnapshot key of item 15 that you already loaded.

Comment: @Thien Kopites yes, I understand its for tracking and getting next values but how to get the key, can I do dataSnapshot.key() ?

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia so, what is your chat ID ?? 
You can set dataSnapshot.key()  for your chat item id, otherwise you can check again in my code, I updated

Comment: one last question. what do I need to pass it to endAt(). my key is: -LMi2xWN... etc i thought endAt will use timestamp but I am confused what will endAt accept. I cant pass int to it.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. I was wrong in my code (i updated).If you orderByKey, startAt would be last key, and If you orderByChild, startAt would be orderByChild's last value. And ofcourse, if you orderByChild("timestamp") you can endAt("timestamp")

Comment: make sure your endAt and startAt are not null or not found :)